# Flex portlets calling web service

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, xfire

Flex portlet is calling a webservice and I am intercepting the calls to check the session credentials using XFire AbstractHandler method implementation. But I am not getting the same httpsession value that is used for login in to the application. I have intercepted the calls using TCPmon also. But no clue..

Do anybody have any idea?

Regards
Vishal

Answer (score 1):

The way java portlets work, you do have different sessions, after all they are packaged in different wars, have different contexts, so on. Where the portal comes in, is as a Java EE servlet filter. So the portal works to keep the necessary portal session information syched up for all the portlets accessing it, while allowing them to keep their own session data within elements of each portlets individual session.

[The specification is fairly readable,](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=168)  and one of the books I found most useful when I started portlets is "Professional Portal Development with Open Source Tools", by Wrox. I don't know if its been updated for [JSR 286](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286) yet, which is the java Portal 2.0 spec.

Comment: Hi Mezmo,

But all portlets will be in same http session. Is it?

Regards
Vishal G

Comment: Yes and no. Every WAR file has its own session. This is maintained at the servlet container level. The portal itself has its own servlet session. Information that needs to be shared from the portal container, to the individual portlets is inserted by the portal filter. This is how session information from different portlets is made inaccessible to each other unless specifically shared. That sharing came in in Portal 2.0 spec.